# Best Way to Submit Dynamic Repeating Form

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, forms

I'm trying to teach myself php and mysql and I'm having trouble with a form I'm working on for a football pool I'm trying to put together. I'm looking for a little help on the best way to submit the data from this form. The form gets data from my database and repeats for the appropriate number of rows. Upon submitting the form each row should be inserted or updated to the database. The data that needs to be submitted is: userid, gameid, pick, and tbPoints.

The form is a little rough as I have not finished it yet. I just cant seem to get the form to submit each row as a new entry to the database, it only submits the last game. I know I have a problem with the loop to submit, but I just can't seem to figure out how to get it. Any help is appreciated!

here is my form:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/t2016.php'); ?>
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_t2016, $t2016);
$query_gamedays = "SELECT DISTINCT schedule.weekDay, schedule.`date` FROM schedule WHERE schedule.weekNum=1";
$gamedays = mysql_query($query_gamedays, $t2016) or die(mysql_error());
$row_gamedays = mysql_fetch_assoc($gamedays);
$totalRows_gamedays = mysql_num_rows($gamedays);
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="" method="post" name="form1">
    <table border="2" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2">
    <tr align="center">
            <td>Time</td>
            <td colspan="3">Matchup</td>
            <td>Current Pick</td>
     </tr>
    <?php do {  
        $day = $row_gamedays['weekDay']; 
        $date = $row_gamedays['date']; 
    ?>
      <tr wrap="nowrap">
            <td colspan="5"><?php echo '<strong>'.$day.'</strong>, '.$date; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php
        mysql_select_db($database_t2016, $t2016);
        $query_sched = "SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE schedule.weekNum=1 AND schedule.weekDay='$day'";
        $sched = mysql_query($query_sched, $t2016) or die(mysql_error());
        $row_sched = mysql_fetch_assoc($sched);
        $totalRows_sched = mysql_num_rows($sched);

    ?>
    <?php do { 
        $gameid = $row_sched['gameID'];
        $time = $row_sched['time'];
        $vteam = $row_sched['visitorID'];
        $hteam = $row_sched['homeID'];

        mysql_select_db($database_t2016, $t2016);
        $query_picks = "SELECT * FROM picks WHERE picks.gameID=$gameid AND picks.userID=1";
        $picks = mysql_query($query_picks, $t2016) or die(mysql_error());
        $row_picks = mysql_fetch_assoc($picks);
        $totalRows_picks = mysql_num_rows($picks);  

        if($totalRows_picks > 0) {
            $pick = $row_picks['pickID'];
            $tbp = $row_picks['tiebreakerPoints'];
        } else {
            $pick = 'No Pick';
            $tbp = '0';
        }

        $vp = '';
        $hp = '';
        if($pick == $vteam) {
            $vp = 'checked';
        } elseif($pick == $hteam) { 
            $hp = 'checked';
        }
    ?>
        <tr align="center">
            <td><?php echo $time; ?></td>

            <td align="right"><?php echo $vteam.'<input type="radio" name="pickID'.$gameid.'[]" value="'.$vteam.'" '.$vp.'>'; ?></td>
            <td align="center"> @ </td>
            <td align="left"><?php echo '<input type="radio" name="pickID'.$gameid.'[]" value="'.$hteam.'" '.$hp.'>'.$hteam; ?></td>

          <td><?php echo $pick; ?></td>     
        </tr>
        <?php if($row_sched['is_tiebreaker'] > 0) { ?>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" align="right" wrap="nowrap"><?php echo 'Enter Tiebreaker Points:    <input type="number" name="tbpoints[]" min="0" value="'.$tbp.'">'; ?></td>
          <td align="center"><?php echo $tbp; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="gameID[]" value="$gameid">
        <input type="hidden" name="userID" value="1">

    <?php } while ($row_sched = mysql_fetch_assoc($sched)); ?>
    <tr>
    <?php } while ($row_gamedays = mysql_fetch_assoc($gamedays)); ?>
      <td colspan="5" align="right" wrap="nowrap">
            <input type="submit" name"submit" value="Submit Picks">
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>



<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($sched);

mysql_free_result($picks);

mysql_free_result($gamedays);
?>
```

again, the form is really rough so please be kind. Thanks for the help

Comment: Each of the html inputs need to be defined as an array so php can work with multiple values i.e. name='pickID' to name='pickID[]'

Comment: Yes Jeff, sorry I forgot to add those in, I had them originally and have changed my code so that the names are now:  pickid.$gameid.[] , gameID[], and tbpoints[]

Comment: I just can't figure out the loop to go through and get each value from the form. The part i'm having the most trouble with is the radio groups, if I only use pickID[] then each radio group will act as one, and I can only submit on pickID value, so by adding the gameid to it, it makes each radio group unique allowing them to work properly

Answer (score 0):

You just loop through these values like a normal array.

```
$gameID = $_POST['gameID'];
for($x=0; $x<count($gameID); $x++ ) { .... }
```

As for the radio buttons/check boxes - you need to give each group a unique name. The only thing to remember with these controls is that if that are not set then nothing is submitted to the server. You need to check if they are part of the post values i.e.

```
if( isset( $_POST['cbPoints'] ) ) { do something }
```

Otherwise you'll get errors when trying to access them.